# how can i get properties of clicked node with neovis

Tags: neo4j, event-handling, click, onclicklistener, neovis

I am using the neo4j graph database and I am using neovis.js to visualize my graph.I visualized the graph but I can't get the info of the clicked node. How can I get properties of a clicked node with neovis.js?

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this,add a click event(https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neovis.js/issues/16)

```
viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
viz.render();

viz.registerOnEvent("completed", (e)=>{
    viz["_network"].on("click", (event)=>{
        console.log($('.vis-tooltip').text()); //get node properties
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view the properties of a node by hovering your cursor over the node.
Clicking of any sort in neovis is used to modify the visualization.
[image: Hover node for Node details]

Comment: I want to print it to the console, then I will use the data I received and redirect to another page.

Comment: You'd have to use other options like the Neo4j Browser, cypher-shell or the [Javascript driver](https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/)

Comment: How do you get this behavior?  I hover and nothing happens...

Comment: @YanKingYin You'd have to define the properties under the labels key. Which version of neovis are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Is this enough for your usecase?

```
viz.registerOnEvent('clickNode', (e) => {
  // e: { nodeId: number; node: Node }
  console.info(e.node.raw.properties);
});
```

Comment: If we want to display them as a tooltip, anyway for that?